# Assert integrality of a macro argument

Tags: c++, c++11, static-assert

I am trying to create a macro that statically asserts that its argument is a strictly positive int.  This is for use in many other of my legacy macros, which up to now simply assume without any check the integrality of their arguments.

In short, I want the static_assert to pass if I have an entry such as:

"4", "24", "42324" etc.,

and I want the static_assert to fail if the argument is something along the lines

"4.0", "3.00", "2.99", "3.01", "-5", "45n3mn", "0", "01", "002", etc., as well as empty entry

Basically, I want to have the assert pass only if the argument in the macro is a clean integer string, which I do via the following "algorithm":

(1) if stringified argument is not just numbers, then fail

(2) if first char is '0', then fail

(3) if empty, then fail

Below is what I currently have, but it doesn't compile due to error "C2057: expected constant expression"  (I am using MSVS2013 but would like to build g++ 4.8 compatible code as well).  I am not sure how to "call" the std::string methods from within the static_assert.

```
#define MyStaticAssert_isInt(num, message) \
    static_assert(std::string(#num).find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos, message) \
    static_assert(std::string(#num).front() != '0', message) \
    static_assert(!std::string(#num).empty(), message)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that (2) should not have the "not" in it :)

Comment: True...condition (2) should state " if first char is '0', then fail"...in other words, we do not want to accept something along the lines of "001"

Answer (score 4):

You could try this user-defined literal:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>

constexpr bool operator ""_pure(char const * s, std::size_t len)
{
  return len == 0 ||
         ('0' <= s[0] && s[0] <= '9' && operator ""_pure(s + 1, len - 1));
}

#define CHECK_INT(X) static_assert(X ## _pure, "Not pure")

int main()
{
  CHECK_INT("123.0");
}
```

You can of course make the stringification part of the macro.

Comment: +1 Nice, first time I've seen `operator ""` applied recursively :)

Comment: Thanks Kerrek.  Very elegant indeed.  Not sure if it fails with "0" or with empty input, though

Comment: @Chrys: No, the details are left for you to fill in.

Answer (score 2):

The following should allow to check character literals at compile-time:

```
constexpr bool is_number_cont( const char* str )
{
    return !*str || ( *str >= '0' && *str <= '9' && is_number_cont( str + 1 ) );
}

constexpr bool is_number( const char* str )
{
    return *str >= '1' && *str <= '9' && is_number_cont( str + 1 );
}

int main()
{
    static_assert( is_number( "123" ), "123 failed" );
    static_assert( is_number( "0" ), "0 failed" );
    static_assert( is_number( "" ), "empty string failed" );
    static_assert( is_number( "1.23" ), "1.23 failed" );
    static_assert( is_number( "abc" ), "abc failed" );
}
```

You can add the check anywhere, including in a macro.

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0839fc614581b0f)

---

In case you are stuck with a pre-C++11 compiler, you can use a manual expansion up to a limited, fixed length:

```
#define is_number(S) \
               S[0]>='1' && S[0]<='9' && \
    (!S[1] || (S[1]>='0' && S[1]<='9' && \
    (!S[2] || (S[2]>='0' && S[2]<='9' && \
    (!S[3] || (S[3]>='0' && S[3]<='9' && \
    (!S[4] || (S[4]>='0' && S[4]<='9' && \
     !S[5]))))))))
```

Expand it if you need to check longer strings, it should be obvious how to do that.

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc2ff569ac60d716)

Comment: This is a great solution, but I am afraid "constexpr" is not supported in MSVS 2013....:(

Comment: Thanks.  MSVS updated compilers do support constexpr.  I will download and experiment further...thanks for introducing me to the concept!